# Group row when no serial on serial table

Tags: sql, sql-server

Is it possible to group the SQL query result when the item column has no serial list in serial table? Currently I split the column qty to row so the user can select serial 1 by 1. Here's my query:

```
SELECT row = ROW_NUMBER() over (ORDER BY t.PARENT), t.PARENT, t.BOMNO, t.COMPONENT, o.Qty, t.UNIT, t.COMPBOMNO, t.ISSERIAL, t.ISLOT
FROM (SELECT ICBOMD.ITEMNO AS [PARENT],
             ICBOMD.BOMNO,
             ICBOMD.COMPONENT,
             ICBOMD.QTY,
             ICBOMD.UNIT,
             ICBOMD.COMPBOMNO,
             ISNULL(ICITEM.SERIALNO, 0) AS [ISSERIAL],
             ISNULL(ICITEM.LOTITEM, 0) AS [ISLOT]
      FROM ICBOMH LEFT OUTER JOIN
           ICBOMD
           ON ICBOMH.ITEMNO = ICBOMD.ITEMNO AND ICBOMH.BOMNO = ICBOMD.BOMNO LEFT OUTER JOIN
           ICITEM
           ON ICITEM.ITEMNO = ICBOMD.COMPONENT
       WHERE ICITEM.STOCKITEM = 1 AND ICBOMD.ITEMNO = 'GAM-001' AND ICBOMD.BOMNO = 'P1' 
      ) t CROSS APPLY
      (SELECT 1
       FROM master..spt_values v
       WHERE v.type = 'P' AND v.number < t.QTY
      ) o(Qty)
```

For example the COMPONENT **GAM-COMP02** has no serial on the serial table. It should be group by and the qty will become 2.

[image]

Below query is how I retrieved serial:

```
SELECT SERIALNUM AS [Serial Number], LOCATION AS [Location],
       CONVERT(DATE, CONVERT(VARCHAR, STOCKDATE)) AS [Stock Date], STATUS AS [Available]
FROM ICXSER
WHERE ITEMNUM = 'GAM-COMP02'
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You may apply Serial number like that

```
  select row_number() over (order by (select 100)) as Slno, * from table
```

Note: But this will assign row_number indeterminate ordering.

For this line `It should be group by and the qty will become 2.` it is better to apply `group by`.

```
 select COMPONENT , count(COMPONENT) as Count from table group by COMPONENT
```

Comment: It does not assign the row number "randomly".  It assigns the row numbers based on an *indeterminate* ordering.  That is not the same as "random".

Comment: I'm sorry but how can I apply those inside the existing query? Is it possible to put the serial checking inside the existing query?

Comment: so what is your expected output